# Add new mime type for media

Tags: php, wordpress, mime-types

I want to upload some dfxp files to media by this code:

```
if ( !function_exists('media_handle_upload') ) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
}



  $id = media_handle_sideload(array('name' =>'test.dfxp', 'tmp_name' =>****/test.dfxp' ));
```

But I get this error:

```
Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.
```

even when I put this function above the code to add the mime type:

```
function custom_upload_mimes( $existing_mimes ) {
    // add webm to the list of mime types
    $existing_mimes['dfxp'] = 'application/dfxp';
    // return the array back to the function with our added mime type
    return $existing_mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
```

And Yes I checked the mimes and I found it.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is mime type called 'application/dfxp' try this

```
$existing_mimes['dfxp'] = 'application/xml';
```

insted of

```
$existing_mimes['dfxp'] = 'application/dfxp';
```